# Can HC-05 Continuously Stream data and read data at the same time?

Tags: arduino-uno, softwareserial, analogread, hc-05

I am trying to have my Arduino Stream an Analog Signal using Bluetooth Module (HC-05) while being able to read commands from another Micro-controller using the same Bluetooth Module.

Currently, I am using Arduino Uno for this.

Comment: What you are asking for really depends on the underlying hardware.  There are so many different Arduino platforms using so many different processors.  And you didn't even specify which Arduino you have.  You didn't even specify the data rate you require for your project.

Comment: If you're using SoftwareSerial then probably no, you can't. SoftwareSerial is strictly half duplex. You can't receive while sending, and if you're sending a lot then you never have time to receive.